# Does installing a deb file add to repository list?

Tags: apt, repository, deb

For example I want to install Google Chrome via deb file. Will it be added to my repository list for apt-get update and apt-get upgrade?

If not, how would I go about updating it and other software installed through deb files?

Comment: Have a look at : [How to Install Software when you're a Windows user](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926)

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the deb file. Google Chrome does add Google's repository, other packages may not. For such packages, you'll have to manually check for updates, by whatever means you got the package in the first place.